# NAS and the Command Prompt

Tags: windows-7, command-line, script, nas, file-permissions

I have a Seagate GoFlex NAS drive. I keep my iTunes folder there. Windows has a map from "\GOFLEX_HOME\GoFlex Home Public" to X:  This all works fine. From Window's Explorer I can drag and drop files around with no issues...

I have a bunch of duplicate files in the iTunes folder so I wrote a script to parse the folder and move any duplicates. The problem is the move fails with:

```
Microsoft JScript runtime error: Permission denied
```

...even though I can do it through the Explorer. Any ideas why?

If I try to run CMD is elevated mode, it no longer sees the X: drive.

PS. The part of the script that moves the file:

```
function moveFile(file)
{
    var xroot = "X:\\dump";
    // Create all the folders
    var fldrs = file.ParentFolder.Path.split("\\");
    for (var i = 1; i < fldrs.length; i++) {
        xroot += "\\" + fldrs[i];
        try {
            fso.CreateFolder(xroot);
        } catch (e) {}
    }
    print(file.Name + " -> " + xroot);
    file.Copy(xroot);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to run your script in elevated mode, then you must map the drive in your script, because in elevated mode it is running as the local administrator so it doesn't have the same drive mappings. Also, if you want to remove duplicate files (based on actual file content and not a duplicate name), I've used [this](http://www.digitalvolcano.co.uk/content/duplicate-cleaner) for the same thing (removing duplicate songs) with good results.